# R - Timer based on column data (Condition has been true for x time) for large data sets

Tags: r, datetime, conditional-statements, elapsedtime

Disclaimer: I'm new to R, I have searched for an answer. There are similar problems, but I'm having issues translating what I've read into something meaningful for my implementation.

I am trying to add a condition timer column, which measures the amount of time  sampleCondition = TRUE. If the Condition returns to false, the timer should reset. NOTE: I'm trying to get rid of the for loop. I'm currently calculating ConditionTime in seconds unit, but it could be minutes for the sample.
End result should look like this: [ConditionTime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyOnc.png)

I am still learning and so far, just end up breaking everything with each attempt I have made to improve for large data sets. (approx 1mil rows) Can someone either provide a sample solution or point me in the right direction? Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

```
#create sample DateTime
DateTime <- c("2017-09-01 09:37:04", "2017-09-01 09:38:04", "2017-09-01 09:39:04", "2017-09-01 09:40:04", "2017-09-01 09:41:04", "2017-09-01 09:42:04", "2017-09-01 09:43:04")
#create sample condition
sampleCondition <- c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0)
#create sample DF
sampleDF <- data.frame(DateTime,sampleCondition)

#calculate the time diff from data point to data point
sampleDF$rowTimeDiff <- c(0,difftime(sampleDF$DateTime[2:length(sampleDF$DateTime)], sampleDF$DateTime[1:(length(sampleDF$DateTime)-1)] ,  units = "secs"))


#check if condition is true (else NA), check if condition was true in the last row. ConditionTime = sum of ConditionTime[previous row] and rowTimeDiff 
for (i in 1:length(sampleDF$DateTime)) {
  sampleDF$ConditionTime[i] <- ifelse(sampleDF$sampleCondition[i] == 1, 
                                      ifelse(is.na(sampleDF$ConditionTime[i-1]), sampleDF$rowTimeDiff[i], sum(sampleDF$ConditionTime[i-1], sampleDF$rowTimeDiff[i]))
                                      , NA ) 
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Thanks again!

EDIT: Added more data to sample for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
x <- sampleDF$sampleCondition

(cumsum(x)-cummax((!x)*cumsum(x)))*60
[1]   0  60   0   0  60 120   0
```

Time test:

```
microbenchmark(
  cumsum(x)-cummax((!x)*cumsum(x))*60
)

Unit: nanoseconds
expr min    lq    mean median     uq   max neval
  60 973 989.5 1357.09   1060 1139.5 23265   100
```

Sample data:

```
sampleDF <- data.frame(
  DateTime=c("2017-09-01 09:37:04", "2017-09-01 09:38:04", "2017-09-01 09:39:04", "2017-09-01 09:40:04", "2017-09-01 09:41:04", "2017-09-01 09:42:04", "2017-09-01 09:43:04"),
  sampleCondition=c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0),
)
```

Comment: That does the job perfectly, and it's very elegant as well. I've scaled this to 140k rows of data and it processed in Nanoseconds. Lightning fast!! Thank you so much for taking the time to assist, I appreciate it very much!

Comment: @JeremiahMyers - You're very welcome. Glad to hear it worked well. Happy coding.